# Why I get: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'patients' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a context and try to pass values to the children:

```
const PatientContext = createContext([{}]);

function App() {
  const [selectedPatient, setSelectedPatient] = useState([]);
  const [patients, setPatients] = useState([{ name: "Username", age: 19 }]);

  async function patientsHasChanged() {
    const patientService = new PatientService();
    const loadedPatients = await patientService.getPatients();
    setPatients(loadedPatients);
  };

  return (
    <div className='app'>
      <PatientContext.Provider value={{selectedPatient, setSelectedPatient, patients, patientsHasChanged}}>
        <Sidebar />
        <Content />
      </PatientContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In one of the components (Sidebar) I get some values:

```
const Sidebar = () => {
    const {patients, setSelectedPatient} = useContext(PatientContext);

    return (
        <div className='sidebar'>
            <div className='search'>
                <input type="text" placeholder='Search' />
                <a href="/TechTask/new"><button>New patient</button></a>
            </div>
            <div className='list'>
                <ul>
                    {patients.map((p) =>
                        <li onClick={setSelectedPatient}>
                            <div className='name'>
                                {p.name}
                            </div>
                            <div className='age'>
                                {p.age}
                            </div>
                        </li>)
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

But as a result, I get an error:

> TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'patients' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined.

As far as I understand, this is because an empty element is taken out of the context, but why? After all, there is data in the context.

Comment: Check `loadedPatients` value, may be it's undefined

Comment: Ensure you are importing and exporting 'PatientContext' and not any of the Producer or Consumer.